# Jenkins: Not looking for any TestNG results

Tags: jenkins, testng

On my Jenkins I have an ANT build file which runs a TestNG suite. In a case of success the TestNG-Jenkins-PlugIn displays the report. But in a case of failure there aren't any reports displayed. As I open the console of the failed build it says:

> Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
>
> TestNG Reports Processing: START
>
> Not looking for any TestNG results.
>
> Finished: FAILURE

I mean, why doesn't it look for any TestNG results? The path for the results is "test-output/*.xml". So it should find any xml files from testng which indeed it finds if the build succeeds. Can anyone help me please? I don't know what's wrong with it.
The TestNG-Plugin is the following: wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin

Comment: It would be nice if the TestNG plugin gave you an option, but I suspect this is by design.

Comment: what do you mean by this? Is this the normal behaviour of the plugin? That barely makes sense, I mean if I don't have the test results if the tests fail.

Comment: Okay, what I have found out so far: version 0.31 does not display failed test results, version 0.26 does it. seems like a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug appears to be fixed in v0.32 - from the wiki:

> Release 0.32 (February 14th, 2012)
>
> Fixed: JENKINS-12648 - Results should be reported for failed/aborted builds as well (Reverted fix for JENKINS-12046 in v0.30)